# xcode 4.5 phonegap clang: error

Tags: xcode, cordova

[image]i am trying to develop an app in phonegap for iphone, when deploy to real phone i am keep getting this error:

ld: library not found for -lCordova
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

In the Xcode project build settings, select the *Summary* tag and add the library `libCordova.a` to the target.  You will probably have to use "Add Other" if it's not in the predefined list.